# How can I mock an exported array with Jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I want to mock an array that's being exported in a TypeScript file. How can I do this with Jest?

I have file like:

```
// names.ts
export const names = ['Alice', 'Bob'];
```

Which is used like:

```
// get-names.ts
import names from './names';

export const getNames = () => { return names };
```

How can I mock this array in Jest?

What I want to do is something like:

```
// get-names.test.ts
import { getNames } from './get-names';

const mockedModule = jest.createMockFromModule('./names');

describe('get names', () => {
  it('gets the list of names', () => {
    mockedModule.names = ['Carol', 'Dave'];
    expect(getNames()).toEqual(['Carol', 'Dave']);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why would you mock a _value_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because that's what is being exported.

Comment: But it doesn't have any _behaviour_, it is what it is. Why not `expect(getNames()).toEqual(['Alice', 'Bob']);`, since that's what it actually returns?

Comment: Because the actual list of names is not the concern of the component I am testing. I want to mocking out the imported list so that I can use different mocked values. Basically, it's the same reason I would want to mock out the HTTP response of a GET request if the list was stored in names.json.

Comment: You _can_ `jest.mock` and provide a mock implementation where `names` has a different value (see https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter), but without a more representative context it's hard to see why you think a boundary here is appropriate. A request would make that a clear network boundary, right now it seems like you're delving into implementation details. Note that `names` isn't the default export of the module, your current import is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) alongside [doMock](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdontmockmodulename) to mock a module for each test:

```
// names.ts
export const names = ["Alice", "Bob"];
```

Make sure you fix your import statement for `names`:

```
// get-names.ts
import { names } from "./names";

export const getNames = () => {
  return names;
};
```

The test file:

```
// get-names.test.ts
describe("get names", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  it("gets the list of names", async () => {
    jest.doMock("./names", () => ({
      __esModule: true,
      names: ["Carol", "Dave"],
    }));
    const { getNames } = await import("./get-names");
    expect(getNames()).toEqual(["Carol", "Dave"]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

```
// get-names.test.ts
import { getNames } from "./get-names";
import { names } from "./names";

jest.mock("./names", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  names: []
}));

describe("names", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // reset (wipe) mocked array
    names.splice(0, names.length);
  });

  it("gets the list of names", () => {
    names.push(...["Carol", "Dave"]);
    expect(getNames()).toEqual(["Carol", "Dave"]);
  });

  it("gets the list of more names", () => {
    names.push(...["Enid", "Fred"]);
    expect(getNames()).toEqual(["Enid", "Fred"]);
  });
});
```

Basically:

- mock `./names`
- import `./names`
- empty the array in a `beforeEach`
- populate the array in each test

Try the codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-sea-71fig3?file=/src/get-names.test.ts:0-561